# How to edit and delete properties of objects within an array on a record

Tags: surrealdb

I am having a hard time editing and deleting objects in an array within a record. I can figure out how to add objects to an array:

```
UPDATE my_table:record_id SET array += {
    id: "id_of_this_object_123456",
    name: "Josh"
    age: 21
}
```

But i dont know how i would update specific properties in the objects within the array. This is my try in doing so, but this does not work:

```
UPDATE my_table:record_id.array MERGE {
    age: 25
} WHERE id == "id_of_this_object_123456"
```

I dont know either how to delete an object from an array. This does not work either:

```
UPDATE my_table:record_id SET parameter -= * WHERE parameters.id == "id_of_this_object_123456"
```

How do i manipulate array of objects within a record depentent on some criteria, e.g. `id` or `name`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out! These two queries work:

Update:

```
UPDATE record_id SET array[WHERE id == "id_of_this_object_123456"] = { 
    id: "id_of_this_object_123456",
    name: "Josh",
    age: 25,
}
```

Delete:

```
UPDATE record_id SET array = array[WHERE id != "id_of_this_object_123456"]
```

For the update solution, i would rather have a `CONTENT` solution, where i dont have to specify all properties, but i have not found a solution for this yet.